# Regex to split and extract value from pipe delimited file

Tags: regex, csv, regex-greedy

I want to split a pipe( | ) delimited file using regex only and extract a particular field at nth position. My current solutions works fine until a blank field appears. I am unable to figure out what i am doing wrong.

Sample Data:

```
asdw|qwe|23344|as||sada||ssss|sdd
```

My partially working solution:

```
^((?:[^|]+\|){3})(?P<error>[^|]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bXvo4T/1

The issue with the current solution is it fails when two consecutive delimiter appears without any content in between, as for position 4 it should return no match but ends up giving no match for all occurences after 4th position. You can try that in the regex101 link shared.

Comment: What language are you using? Most languages have CSV libraries which are more robust than using a regular expression.

Comment: Whenever you give an example please state the desired result. Here do you wish to return the string between the 3rd and 4th pipe? Must the string of interest be between pipes or could it be between the beginning of the string and the first pipe or between the last pipe and the end of the string. You say you have a "partially-working solution". In what way is it unsatisfactory. Please edit.

Comment: Suppose you want the string after the 3rd pipe, between the 3rd and 4th pipes if there are at least 4 pipes, else the string after the 3rd pipe. Moreover, suppose the string after *pipe zero* is regarded as the string that precedes the first pipe or the entire string if there are no pipes. If the regex engine supports `\K` (as does PCRE, Ruby and others), and you specify the 3rd pipe, for example, you could match the string of interest with the regular expression `^(?:[^|]*\|){3}\K[^|]+`.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t4bt5g/1)...

Comment: ... As seen at the link, `\K` causes the regex engine to reset the beginning of the match to the current location in the string and to discard all previously-consumed characters from the reported match.

Comment: @CarySwoveland have updated my question. Your solution works too, you can post it as answer. Thanks alot, didn't knew about `\K` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to swap the 'One or more token `+`' with a 'Zero or more token `*`' as it looks like it's getting stuck with no chars between the two pipes.

I think the following should give you the result you are looking for:

```
^((?:[^|]*\|){3})(?P<error>[^|]+)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the job. Additionally if you can add; how to set a default value if there is zero token at the required position?

Comment: I think that might be beyond the capabilities of pattern matching and would have to be handled programatically depending on the environment you are using this in.  I could very well be mistaken though, maybe someone else can shed some further light.